# Deleting tomcat log files automatically for every 2 days.

Tags: tomcat

I would like to automatically delete tomcat log files for every 2 days.To do that,  I wrote a script in /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat but it is not working.I am using ubuntu 16.04 dist.

```
/opt/tomcat/logs/*.*.* {

    daily
    missingok
    rotate 2
    missingok
    nomail
    postrotate
            /usr/bin/find /opt/tomcat/logs/ -name "*.*.*" -type f -
  mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
    endscript
 }
```

Suggest me answres to delete tomcat logs. Please help.

Comment: `but it is not working` ... what is actually happening? (not my downvote)

Comment: old log files are not deleted

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple Cronjob where you execute a simple bash-file which removes the files in your wished directory

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron/

```
rm -r /opt/tomcat/logs/* #or whatever you want to delete
```

Comment: Scheduling crontab helped me.Thanks for the idea markus